# Different convergence radius for different power series of the same function.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

i was playing around with $$\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}$$

I got 3 different series's:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{x}{(x+1)^2})^n*(\frac{1}{x}) $$ 
which converges when $|\frac{x}{(x+1)^2}|<1$

the second one:
$$\frac{4}{3}*\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt 3})^{2n}$$
which converges when $|2x-1|^2<1$ and $x^2+x+1\neq 0$

and the third:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{3n}-x^{3n+1}$$
which converged when $|x|^3<1$

How is that a possible? it would make sense that some of the series wont fit for some x's , but how the convergence rate be different?

thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean "convergence rate" or rather "convergence radius" (because that's actually what you are talking about in the rest of your post)?

Comment: yes, thank you, i did not notice i mixed the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no problem with your 3 examples since they are totally different representations which don't have to have the same convergence radius.

An easier example to investigate this issue would be the following:
Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. This function is defined for all non-zero $x$.
Now, by the famous geometric series, one could write this as
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-x)^k$$
But this only converges iff $|1-x|<1$ i.e. $-2<x<0$.
Alternatively, we can write $$f(x)=-f(-x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} -(1+x)^k$$
which converges iff $|1+x|<1$ i.e. $0<x<2$.

So this should be even more striking, since there is no value for $x$ where both the series converge.

But nonetheless, both series are perfectly well representations for $f(x)$ (though only for particular values of $x$).

Comment: Thank you! your example clarified it very well, will +1 as soon as i get 15 rep here :)